# Examples of TVS with no non-trivial open convex subsets

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, big-list, examples, topological-vector-spaces

I give [here](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/a-topological-vector-space-with-no-non-trivial-continuous-linear-form/) the classical example of the space $E = L^p([0,1])$ which has no open convex subsets apart from $\emptyset$ and $E$. Consequently, there is no non-trivial continuous linear form on $E$.

Apart from spaces of functions or sequences, do you have examples of Topological Vector Spaces (TVS) with no open convex subsets other than $\emptyset$ and the space itself?

Also, do you have an example of a TVS with no non-trivial continuous linear form but which contains an open convex subset different from $\emptyset$ and the space itself?

Comment: For what it's worth, this construction of TVS with dual space $\{0\}$ works for $L^p(X)$ where $X$ is any measure space with no atoms and $0 < p < 1$. In this way the sequence spaces and functions on $[0,1]$ that you describe are special instances of a more general construction. See http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/lpspace.pdf.

Comment: "Apart from spaces of functions or sequences" Doesn't that exclude basically all naturally occurring spaces? I mean the whole point of functional analysis and the study of TVS is to understand certain function spaces better.

Comment: @Ricardo l'll be interested in having a big list of examples for my first question. I'll raise a separate topic for the second question.

Comment: @Johannes Hahn. You're probably right. I just mean that I'm also interested by "strange objects".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$W^{p,\infty}(\mathbb R^n)$ for $0<p<1$, which is the space of all smooth functions such that each partial derivative  is in $L^p$. Instead of $\mathbb R^n$ one can also take a Riemannian manifold of bounded geometry, where now each iterated covariant derivative has to be in $L^p$ (of sections of the appropriate tensor bundle).

One can also go to Denjoy-Carleman ultra differentiable functions of this type, like 
$W^{\{M\},p}(\mathbb R^n)$ or $W^{(M),p}(\mathbb R^n)$ for $p<1$, as described in

- Andreas Kriegl, Peter W. Michor, Armin Rainer: An exotic zoo of diffeomorphism groups on ℝn. Ann. Glob. Anal. Geom. 47, 2 (2015), 179-222. [(pdf)](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/exotic-zoo.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in the paper [*Nearly exotic topologies on normed spaces* (1971)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=295035) where N. T. Peck shows that any infinite-dimensional normed space can be re-topologized in such a (weaker) way that the new topology admits no nontrivial continuous linear functionals. (Hence also, if I understand [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/206856) correctly, no nontrivial open convex subsets.)